# Is there any chance to hack codeigniter sessions?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, session-cookies

currently i am working with CI. i am using the CI session library it saves all session values in a cookie. is there any possibilities to hack this(session variables) by using plugin like web developer in mozilla.

Comment: Why would you want to hack session variables cookies ?

Comment: i dont want to hack.  if some hacked the website sessions they can do anything. now i am using database session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, sessions are made by 4 infos:

1. The user's unique Session ID (this is a statistically random string
   with very strong entropy, hashed with MD5 for portability, and
   regenerated (by default) every five minutes)
2. The user's IP Address
3. The user's User Agent data (the first 120 characters of the browser
   data string)
4. The "last activity" time stamp.

Plus your own session datas, of course. 3 of this four datas don't need to be secure, while the first should be quite reliable, even though using MD5, I didn't dive into the code to actually see if it is so (and I'm no security expert).
The security level of the latter infos depends on what kind of information you're storing there, and how well you treat them before storing.

You can also decide to store sessions using the database instead, which will be a safer option (provided you don't screw up allowing sql injections!).

Note also that:

> If you have the encryption option enabled, the serialized array will
>   be encrypted before being stored in the cookie, making the data highly
>   secure and impervious to being read or altered by someone. More info
>   regarding encryption can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html), although the Session
>   class will take care of initializing and encrypting the data
>   automatically.

So well, they should be quite secure; if you don't trust them enough, you're free to hash or encrypt your data how much you want, or still make use of PHP native Sessions without problems.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what sort of information you actually end up storing in the cookies. If there is a `$_COOKIE['is_admin']` with value `"false"` .. well ..

Essentially you have to examine information you actually store on the user's computer. Usually for the sessions it only stores the `PHPSESSID`, which contains a hash and the rest of values stay on the server.